# Cannot install anything from Microsoft store on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, windows-store-app, windows-store, windows-10-v1803

I have a weird problem with my Windows 10 Pro setup. I want to install Ubuntu bash from the Microsoft store but whenever I click on get/install in the store nothing happens. Working message briefly appears and the store windows kind of reloads and the button goes back to get/install. Any ideas? I tried resetting the store cache and enabling Linux Subsystem through power shell all without luck. Same thing happens when I tried installing anything from MS store. My system has all up to date updates and it's pretty much brand new as I have only just unboxed this laptop.

Update: build number 1803.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was having the same issue. I uninstalled Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL), rebooted, reinstalled WSL, rebooted. Then I opened the Windows Store, logged out, logged back in, and was able to install.

Comment: I was able to resolve this same issue in a similar way - by rebooting my PC, then signing out of the Windows Store app, then signing back in.

Comment: What is WSL? @josephbales

Comment: @Cherona see my update

Answer (score 5):

What I did to resolve this issue was simply logging out of and then back into the Windows Store App. I'm running Windows 10 x64 build 1803.

Comment: That's probably also a valid solution for most. Can't verify it now mu issue has been resolved but it makes sense. It's clearly some post update store issue.

Comment: TL;TR: This should be marked as answer to this question. I can confirm simply logging out and back in to Microsoft Store solves the problem. I have verified this procedure on two computers with Windows 10 x64 1803. No need to reinstall WSL.

Comment: This should be the first thing to try, before reinstalling or restoring anything!

Comment: @mloskot - We have a case of duplicate answers being submitted a short amount of time between one another.  The author of the question is the sole person who decides which answer should be accepted.

Comment: @Ramhound Understood. I just made a suggestion.